# Can you set the tableView datasource values in "connectionDidFinishLoading"?

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on my first JSON example in objective-c and came across [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) great tutorial that I'm trying to reproduce.  Along the way I decided to push the JSON returned into my already working tableView (just to ensure I could do something w/ the data in the view).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

  responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.unpossible.com/misc/lucky_numbers.json"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSArray *luckyNumbers = [responseString JSONValue];

    NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Nums "];

    for (int i = 0; i < [luckyNumbers count]; i++)
        [text appendFormat:@"%@", [luckyNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];

  self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", text, @"Last", nil];
}
```

What I've found is that when I set the array in "connectionDidFinishLoading" it shows up as nothing in the running application - yet if I set this directly in the "viewDidLoad" method with 3 simple string values it shows up fine.

When I debug the running application I see the JSON response and the string looks valid (no issues that I can see).

Is the datasource for my tableView already set in stone before this "connectionDidFinishLoading" method or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial question was solved by this solution:

At the end of my "connectionDidFinishLoading" method I call a method on the appDelegate called "jsonFinished".

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  //do all the json work and set the array that I'm using as my datasource

  self.movies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", "Last", nil];

  [appDelegate jsonFinished]; //have the app delegate do the refresh call back
}
```

Then inside the appDelegate I simply provide an implementation for the "jsonFinished" method that does a refresh of the UITableView

```
- (void)jsonFinished
{
  moviesController.refreshDisplay;
}
```

And in the "refreshDisplay" method I do the reloadData on the tableView

```
- (void)refreshDisplay
{
    [moviesTableView reloadData];
}
```

And now after the data is loaded the appDelegate fires off the method that reloads the data for tableView

Answer (score 2):

Your `UITableView` will call upon its `DataSource` for data once initially, presumably sometime after `viewDidLoad`.  After that first load, it will only request data as it needs it (i.e. as you scroll to different cells.)  If you want to make it refresh its contents when your data is ready (like after you've received your URL data), call `[tableView reloadData]`.